# How do I find out why I am getting an EOSError code 5 - Access Denied registering a service?

Tags: web-services, delphi, service, nt

I am getting an EOSError code 5 - Access Denied when the 
TServiceApplication attempts to register the service with the 
ServiceManager.

I am using XE2 Win7 64 bit.  The error occurs for both 32 and 64 bit 
targets.

I have a datamodule that uses ADO to connect to a database, and the web 
services server code.  All the code is used in a WinUI project which 
works.  I also have an untested ISAPI DLL based on the same core code.

This is the first time I have tried incorporating a Web Services Server 
into an NT Service.

I have traced the VCL code that produces the error at line 1027 of 
Vcl.SvcMgr but I don't know why I am getting the Access Denied error.  I 
have written other  NT Services that connect to the database through ADO 
and have not encountered such an error (although written with XE).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You are likely encountering a UAC permissions issue that expects you to run the service install process in an elevated state, such as from a cmd.exe instance that was launched via the "Run as administrator" option, but you are not actually doing so.  If you are having this problem with only some services and not others, then the affected services likely do not contain a UAC manifest but contain characteristics that are triggering UAC's Installer Detection feature, typically (but not restricted to) having reserved keywords in your service's filename or version resource.

Comment: But besides asking on Stack Overflow and getting educated guesses about it, *how do you find out why* you get an "access denied" message? That's what the question asks.

Comment: There is no way to determine the SPECIFIC REASON why access is being denied (that would be a security hole if the reason was reported to the caller that failed).  You just have to know that an Access Denied error is related to permissions, so you have to look at what your app is doing that touches permission-secured resources until you find the culprit.

Comment: Who said it needed to be reported to the caller? Maybe it's reported somewhere else, where someone with administrative privileges could read it.

Comment: Sometimes messages get logged in the System Event Log (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer), but I don't think this is one of those times.